# Filtering a Pivot Table Based on Variable Range

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table, vba

My objective is to filter a pivot table using a range in another sheet. This range pulls data from a 3rd sheet, which is the data dump that kicks off a whole hosts of formulas and changes every time it is used.

I have the below code but what I can see it doing is running through each Pivot Table field, comparing it to the range, and then removing the filter. I have 32,000 fields that need to be checked so the current macro is too slow to use.

Could anyone help me fix the code so that it only filters based on values in the range that are Not Blank?

```
Sub PT()
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PI As PivotItem
Set PT = Sheets("Pivot_Sheet").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
With Sheets("Pivot_Sheet").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Product")
.ClearAllFilters
End With
For Each PI In PT.PivotFields("Product").PivotItems
PI.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:J100"),
PI.Name) > 0
Next PI
Set PT = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Put your code in code tags please.

Comment: Sorry, Code tagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is going to be slow on many, many counts. Have a read of my [blogpost on this subject](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/) if you're interested in learning about the bottlenecks to avoid when filtering PivotTables.

The below code should get you started. If you have any questions, just holler.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterPivot()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim i As Long
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim vList As Variant

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Product")

vList = Application.Transpose(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:J100"))

pt.ManualUpdate = True 'Stops PivotTable from refreshing after each PivotItem is changed

With pf

    'At least one item must remain visible in the PivotTable at all times, so make the first
    'item visible, and at the end of the routine, check if it actually  *should* be visible
    .PivotItems(1).Visible = True

    'Hide any other items that aren't already hidden.
    'Note that it is far quicker to check the status than to change it.
    ' So only hide each item if it isn't already hidden
    For i = 2 To .PivotItems.Count
        If .PivotItems(i).Visible Then .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
    Next i

    'Make the PivotItems of interest visible
    On Error Resume Next 'In case one of the items isn't found
    For Each vItem In vList
        .PivotItems(vItem).Visible = True
    Next vItem
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Hide the first PivotItem, unless it is one of the items of interest
    On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(UCase(Join(vList, "|")), UCase(.PivotItems(1))) = 0 Then .PivotItems(1).Visible = False
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        .ClearAllFilters
        MsgBox Title:="No Items Found", Prompt:="None of the desired items was found in the Pivot, so I have cleared the filter"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End With

pt.ManualUpdate = False

End Sub
```