# Trying to use VBA to filter my Pivot Table based on Year and Period values in cells D2 and E2

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to filter my Pivot Table using VBA so it will filter based on a Period and a Year in cells D2 and E2 respectively. I have the below code which is to filter by the year and works without having the Fiscal Period in the Columns but when I put the Fiscal Period in the columns it debugs at the `Field.ClearAllFilters` and `Field.CurrentPage = Year` lines. Can someone please help me find a fix for this?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Worksheets("CY PT").Range("E2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim Year As String

Set PT = Worksheets("CY PT").PivotTables("CY PT")
Set Field = PT.PivotFields("Fiscal Year")
Year = Worksheets("CY PT").Range("E2").Value

With PT
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = Year
PT.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Does it give you an error on those lines? If so, what is it?

Comment: Any particular reason for the PT.RefreshTable line?

Comment: Ok, I am now getting the below errors:
-On the If Intersect line
Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed
-On Field.ClearAllFilters line
Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
Method 'ClearAllFilters' of object 'PivotField' failed

And I'm pretty sure I get the same error on the Field.CurrentPage = Year line but my Excel keeps crashing before I can get to that one

Answer (score 1):

The .CurrentPage method only applies to PageFields. Sounds like you are trying to filter RowFields. So your options are:

- Change your fields to be PageFields; or
- Use a Slicer; or
- Use a PageField filter dropdown mascarading as a Data Validation
  dropdown (like I outline at
  http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/08/16/sync-pivots-from-dropdown/
  ); or
- Iterate through the PivotItems collection for each field, and set the
  .Visible status of everything but the selected items to FALSE.

If you choose the last option, you need to be aware this can take a while. See the code I posted at [Filtering a Pivot Table Based on Variable Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487023/filtering-a-pivot-table-based-on-variable-range/46536882#46536882) to get an understanding of how to do this efficiently. Also give my post at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/ a read.